# How can I align this equation in latex?

Tags: math-mode

[image]

How can Ii handle this equation to prevent it to out from the page 
I wrote it in latex as form

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
g^{\prime}(x)=\frac{(27+520x^2+560x^4)((14555+1012\sqrt{205})\log(-65+4\sqrt{205}-140 x^2)+7(205-4\sqrt{205})\log(65+4\sqrt{205}+ 140x^2))}{492(65+4\sqrt{205}+140x^2)(27+4(65+4\sqrt{205})x^2)}
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please  post a compilable code illustrating your problem?

Comment: i wrote this equation as like that in latex \begin{eqnarray*}
g(x)=---------------
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: i don't  know write here equations as latex !! so i write it just text

Comment: Do you mean you don't have any latex code on your computer???

Comment: @user193663 You could, for example, to use this LaTeX equation editor online https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php to create the equation.

Comment: LyX makes it relatively easy to write the LaTeX equations: https://www.lyx.org

Comment: @AndréC  - Does lyx know about the `\splitfrac` macro? :-)

Comment: @Mico I don't use LyX and therefore I can't answer you. My nephew used it to write his thesis and he told me that it saved him a lot of time to write the complicated equations of fluid mechanics.

Answer (score 6):

I would use a `\splitfrac` macro (provided by the `mathtools` package) to split the very long numerator term into two parts.

[image]

Note that I replaced the outermost pair of round parentheses with `\big` square brackets. This change should make it easier for your readers to find their way around the numerator term.

Finally, do also note that there's no point in employing an `eqnarray*` environment here -- quite apart from the fact that `eqnarray` is deprecated and should not be used any longer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for \splitfrac macro
\begin{document}
\[
g'(x)=\frac{%
   \splitfrac{(27+520x^2+560x^4)\bigl[(14555+1012\sqrt{205}\,)\log(-65+4\sqrt{205}-140 x^2)}{%
              +7(205-4\sqrt{205}\,)\log(65+4\sqrt{205}+ 140x^2)\bigr]}}{%
   492(65+4\sqrt{205}+140x^2)(27+4(65+4\sqrt{205}\,)x^2)}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: mico  thanks for your helping

Answer (score 3):

I propose  3 other possibilities, using each the medium-size commands from `nccmath` (ca 80 % of \displaystyle), with the `geometry` package, which produces by default more decent margins if you don't use marginal notes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}
\
\begin{flalign*}
 & g'(x)= & & & & \\ & \mfrac{%
  (27+520x^2+560x^4)\bigl[(14555+1012\sqrt{205}\,)\log(-65+4\sqrt{205}-140 x^2)%
              +7(205-4\sqrt{205}\,)\log(65+4\sqrt{205}+ 140x^2)\bigr]}{%
   492(65+4\sqrt{205}+140x^2)(27+4(65+4\sqrt{205}\,)x^2)}
\end{flalign*}

\begin{multline*}
 g'(x)=(27+520x^2+560x^4) \times \\ \mfrac{%
(14555+1012\sqrt{205}\,)\log(-65+4\sqrt{205}-140 x^2)%
              +7(205-4\sqrt{205}\,)\log(65+4\sqrt{205}+ 140x^2)}{%
   492(65+4\sqrt{205}+140x^2)(27+4(65+4\sqrt{205}\,)x^2)}
\end{multline*}

\begin{multline*}
g'(x)=\mfrac{(27+520x^2+560x^4)}{ 492(65+4\sqrt{205}+140x^2)(27+4(65+4\sqrt{205}\,)x^2)}\times \\
\medmath{\bigl[(14555+1012\sqrt{205}\,)\log(-65+4\sqrt{205}-140 x^2)%
              +7(205-4\sqrt{205}\,)\log(65+4\sqrt{205}+ 140x^2)\bigr]}
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your clear and helping  bernard